# Как передать неизвестное количество аргументов в super в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Стоит NodeJS 4.2.1 LTS

Беру из примера код

```js
var someArgs = ["a", "b", "c"];

// Using the spread operator with someArgs
console.log(...someArgs);

// Is equivalent to this
console.log("a", "b", "c");
```

Запускаю в консоли и получаю ошибку

```js
test.js:32
console.log(...someArgs);
            ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

Хотя такой код без проблем отработал в хроме последней версии. Вопрос в чем, это должно работать в NodeJS или нет? Может я не правильно что-то делаю? Тогда как правильно?

Answer (score 4):

Оператор [spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) доступен в Node.js 4 (LTS) только под флагом, однако в [недавно вышедшей Node.js 5](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/) (не LTS!) уже работает из коробки. Чтобы использовать spread в Node.js 4, процесс нужно запускать с флагом `--harmony`, правда флаг нужен не для всех ES6 фич ([тут подробнее](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.0.0/)). Запуск с флагом:

```
$ node --harmony
$ > console.log(...[1,2,3])
$ 1 2 3
```

или

```
$ node --harmony main.js
```

[Здесь](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) можно найти замечательную таблицу с информацией о том, какие фичи ES6 поддерживаются на каких платформах.

Как Chrome, так и Node.js работают на одном движке - 
v8, но так как развитие движка диктуется стороной Chrome, то разработчикам Node.js нужно подстраиваться под все обновления движка, поэтому внедрить и выкатить стабильную версии чаще всего получается не так быстро. Собственно из-за этого многие фичи ES6 первыми появляются в Chrome.